# Checking out and then editing an old commit with git

Tags: git, svn

In my project, I had two commits; A, and then B, both of which were pushed to the remote.

However I realised that my changes in commit B were a bad idea and reverted back to commit A using `git checkout A`.

I then made some changes to commit A, making commit C, which is what I want to then push to my remote as the latest commit. However when I do this, it only pushes the differences between A and C onto the current version of the remote, which is B; in other words, it applies commit C to commit B.

How can I get my local copy onto the remote as a *new* commit, so that the commit history looks like: A,  B,  C (i.e. without reverting B - I still want B in my commit history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rewrite history, you should simply commit a revert for commit B:

```
git revert B
git commit
```

Comment: Ah, to clarify (see the edit I made), I want to keep B in my commit history. I want to push C as a commit on top of B

Comment: It turns out a revert *does* keep the reverted commit in the history, which is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a patch with differences between A and C and apply it on top of B to create a brand new commit, like this:

```
git diff A C > patch.git
git checkout B
...
```

At this point make sure that your working directory is clean.

```
git apply patch.git
...
```

The command above will change only the working directory. So, you need to add the files by yourself.

```
git add ...
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *interactive rebase* which allows you to shuffle around the order of commits. By running `git rebase -i HEAD^^^` you can go back the last three commits; you'll be given a file with commits by hash. Simply edit the file by moving lines up/down to arrange them in the desired order, then save the file and git will apply those changes in that order for you.

Comment: I wrote more about rebasing http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/06/git-tip-of-week-rebasing.html and http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/06/git-tip-of-week-rebasing-revisited.html if you're interested in finding more about what they are.

Comment: But the order of my commits is right: A, then B, then C. The problem is that I want commit C to include the reversion to A as well as the new edits. Instead it's just including the new edits on top of B (without the reversion)

Comment: So do `git revert A` to create a `-A` commit, then do `git rebase -i HEAD^^` to perform an interactive rebase of the `-A` and `C` commits, then do a `squash` instead of an `edit` for the second commit so that it becomes a `C-A` commit.